# How to use the method "UnicodeSegmentation::graphemes"

Tags: rust

While trying to reverse a string, I found the method mentioned in the title

i.e. **UnicodeSegmentation::graphemes**

I referred to the official documentation for usage, but there were two different references which bothered me a lot.

the [first](https://unicode-rs.github.io/unicode-segmentation/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html?search=) one works but the [second](https://docs.rs/unicode-segmentation/1.2.1/unicode_segmentation/struct.Graphemes.html) does not.

To be specific:
the function I coded using the first method:

```rust
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

pub fn reverse(input: &str) -> String {
    UnicodeSegmentation::graphemes(input, true).rev().collect::<String>()
}
```

and the function I coded using the second method:

```rust
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

pub fn reverse(input: &str) -> String {
    input.UnicodeSegmentation::graphemes(true).rev().collect::<String>()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first link is up-to-date. The second is to the documentation for version 1.2.0.  There is a button on the bar at the head of the page to “Go to latest version.”

Comment: Oh, my bad, I have not noticed it. Thanks for that.

Comment: Actually, there is a mistake in my second version. It also works when I implement like this: **input.graphemes(true).rev().collect::<String>()**